# Loading php extension in windows 10 fails

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, 64-bit, php

I'm trying to install the APC OPCache. After downloading the file php_apc.dll to the ext subfolder I added the following line to the php.ini:

```
[PHP]
...
extension=php_apc.dll

[apc]
apc.enabled=1
```

When I now start the apache server I get the following warning in my PHP Log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_apc.dll'
```

When I open the path C:\xampp\php\ext I see the file php_apc.dll ... there are no spaces in the filename.
Also I wrote a test script and in fact e.g. the function apc_add(...) is not defined.

My specs:

- APC dll v3.1.13 (32 bit)
- PHP v 7.0.6
- Apache 2.4 (32 bit)
- Windows 10 Home 64 Bit

My user is local administrator and has full access to all folders and files in the PHP folder.

I can post the full php -i output if you want as well (or provide a download to a txt).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified you downloaded the appropriate file (I.e 32-bit or 64-bit) which is based on Apache not your OS.  Edit your question...

Comment: I edited my specs info. Both apache and the dll are 32 Bit